# is final fit with X,y or X_train , y_train?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I split the dataset with

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

and the fit

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf_probs = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
score = log_loss(y_test, clf_probs)
print(score)
```

is final submission with

```
clf.fit(X,y) or clf.fit(X_train,y_train)???
```

Comment: Your final production model should use all available data since it will in general give you better model performance due to more data. Hence X, y. You should still report your model's performance based off your test set, however

Comment: so clf.fit(X,y)? right?

Comment: please take a look at this post https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/is-it-always-better-to-use-the-whole-dataset-to-train-the-final-model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it always better to use the whole dataset to train the final model?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/is-it-always-better-to-use-the-whole-dataset-to-train-the-final-model)

Answer (score 0):

1. Training dataset is something that you use to train your
   dataset(data    which the model learns upon).
2. Validation dataset is that part of your data which is not used to
   train your model, but to check the model's performance and optimize
   it further. Here, as the model is optimized based on its performance
   on the validation dataset, so according to experts, your model though
   indirectly, has 'seen' the validation data as you might unknowingly
   create a bias towards the validation data by optimizing the model to
   perform better on the validation data only.
3. The stage of testing the models, comes after all the optimization(by
   that time your model has processed (but not trained on) the validation
   data). So, once you think your model is
   optimized (you simply can't know it). Now you can and should use validation data also to train
   the model along with the training data.
4. The testing data on the other hand is that part of your data which is
   completely unknown to model(that is neither it is used to train nor
   to validate the model). It is the completely unbiased performance
   check of your model.

Usually in case of competitions, the data you are given, since it has labels, it should be used to **train and optimize** you model. But testing should always be done only after the model has been trained on **all the labeled data**, that includes your training(X_train, y_train) and validation data(X_test, y_test).

Hence you should submit the prediction after seeing whole labeled data :- Hence clf.fit(X, Y)

I know this long explanation was not necessary, but one should know why you do what you do.

Hope it helps, thanks!!